# ggplot reorder y-axis by value of x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have this data set:

```
bizdev        company                   date       category  
  <chr>         <chr>                     <date>     <chr>     
1 Jerry Harding Jones, Figueroa and Moon  2020-04-06 Mid-tier  
2 Steve Vargas  Stanley, Porter and Mccoy 2020-04-24 Indie     
3 Steve Vargas  Gardner and Sons          2020-04-19 Indie     
4 Jerry Harding Parks-Chen                2020-04-11 Indie     
5 Jerry Harding Bond Group                2020-04-06 Indie     
6 David Burton  Lopez-Johnson             2020-05-07 Enterprise
```

I try to produce a bar chart after transformation.

```
consol <- df %>% mutate(meeting_month = as_factor(month(date, abbr = TRUE, label = TRUE)), .keep = 'unused') %>%
  group_by(bizdev, category, meeting_month) %>% summarise(total_meeting = n())
```

```
# Groups:   bizdev, category [22]
   bizdev       category   meeting_month total_meeting
   <chr>        <chr>      <ord>                 <int>
 1 Bobby Adams  Enterprise Apr                       2
 2 Bobby Adams  Indie      Mar                      12
 3 Bobby Adams  Indie      Apr                      13
 4 Bobby Adams  Indie      May                      12
 5 Bobby Adams  Mid-tier   Mar                       6
 6 Bobby Adams  Mid-tier   Apr                       6
 7 Bobby Adams  Mid-tier   May                       3
 8 David Burton Enterprise May                       2
 9 David Burton Indie      Mar                      30
10 David Burton Indie      Apr                      31
```

y-axis of bar chart is re-arrange by the value of x-axis with code below:

```
consol %>% ggplot(aes(x = total_meeting, y = reorder(bizdev, -total_meeting), fill = category)) 
+ geom_bar(stat = 'identity') 
+ theme_classic()
```

Value at the Y-axis isn't fully order from lowest to highest. Notice 'Steve Vargas' recorded higher total_meeting than 'Joel English'. The position isn't right.

Anyone please advise.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If this does not work, please provide an reproducible example as I have not tested on my machine.

```
consol <- df %>%
  mutate(meeting_month = as_factor(month(date, abbr = TRUE, label = TRUE)), .keep = "unused") %>%
  group_by(bizdev, category, meeting_month) %>%
  summarise(total_meeting = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(bizdev) %>%
  mutate(real_total = sum(total_meeting))

consol %>% ggplot(aes(x = total_meeting, y = reorder(bizdev, -real_total), fill = category))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
theme_classic()
```